# How to know if a script was included inside another script

Tags: php, post, include

I am new to PHP and very likely I am using the incorrect approach because I am not used to think like a PHP programmer.

I have some files that include other files as dependencies, these files need to have global code that will be executed if `$_POST` contains certain values, something like this

```
if (isset($_POST["SomeValue"]))
 {
    /* code goes here */
 }
```

All the files will contain this code section, each one it's own code of course.

The problem is that since the files can be included in another one of these files, then the code section I describe is executed in every included file, even when I post trhough AJAX and explicitly use the URL of the script I want to POST to.

I tried using the `$_SERVER` array to try and guess which script was used for the post request, and even though it worked because it was the right script, it was the same script for every included file.

Question is:

- Is there a way to know if the file was included into another file so I can test for that and skip the code that only execute if `$_POST` contains the required values?

**Note**: The files are generated using a python script which itself uses a c library that scans a database for it's tables and constraints, the c library is mine as well as the python script, they work very well and if there is a fix for a single file, obviously it only needs to be performed to the python script.

I tell the reader (*potential answerer*) about this because I think it makes it clear that I don't need a solution that works over the already existant files, because they can be re-generated.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like `include_once`? - **[info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)**

Comment: If you are new PHP and you're going to do some serious things, checkout symfony, zend or other frameworks. What you want is something a professional would never face, because you can do very very dirty strange thing PHP. In a framework context it's getting more structured with classes and you won't every manually include files then. This is also part of your environment. if you just want to hack around, than include a file, which has the `if(isset(...))` and the additional code in it.

Comment: @Aitch the reason I don't use a framework is because I never feel comfortable using them, just like `jquery` I really really try to do it, but I simply can't. I did solve it now just a combination of `__FILE__` and `$_SERVER`. And also I am kind of writing a framework, because all I will need when it's ready is just a Postgres database, and run the python script I will have all the forms that I need generated. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Aitch: one can do "dirty strange" things in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sounds of it you could make some improvements on your code structure to completely avoid this problem. However, with the information given a simple flag variable should do the trick:

```
if (!isset($postCodeExecuted) && isset($_POST["SomeValue"]))
{
    /* code goes here */
    $postCodeExecuted = true;
}
```

This variable will be set in the global namespace and therefore it will be available from everywhere.

Comment: I solved the problem, with an elegant method, but it's not good to delete this question and I appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing this

```
$caller = str_replace($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], "", __FILE__);
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" and $caller === $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])
    performThisAction();
```